# К какому разряду лексики вы бы отнесли следующее выражение?

Tags: лексика

К какому типу лексики относится выражение "разрешите обратиться"? Армейский жаргон, специальная лексика?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Языковая норма уставного речевого общения в военной лексике. Слова «разрешите обратиться», не являясь приветствием, часто предшествуют ему:

> — Разрешите обратиться, товарищ генерал армии! ― подбежал к командующему
>   Ираклий Соломонович. [Вацлав Михальский. Прощеное воскресенье //
>   Октябрь, 2009]